# Rename all files in subfolders - replace string in filename

Tags: bash, rename, directory, subdirectory

I want to rename all files in a folder and its subfolders.

I need to change the string `HEX20` to the string `HEX8`.
Some filenames have other numbers, so I cannot simply change the `20` to an `8`.

An example of the full path is:

```
\\FRDS01006\z188018\FEM\Linear\HEX20\3HEX20\3HEX20.bof
```

I would like to do the same replacement for the folder names.

Comment: Mention the full pattern of filename you have.

Comment: Please add what you have tried and why it isn't working.

Comment: So far nothing. That's the second line of code I'm trying to write in BASH... In order to give a suggestion, I would need at least some basic knowledge, which hopefully you'll help me gain. Thanks!

Comment: Please write your expected result for the example you provide.

Comment: There's a Perl-based `prename` (aka `rename` — but there's also a more limited command also called `rename`) that can do the job.  However, you have to make sure the renamed directories exist — or rename directories before you rename any files.  Be cautious — you can run into problems quite easily if you rename a directory while a program is still searching under that directory.  Also, since you're using backslashes, are you running on Windows?  If so, the problems you face are different from those on Unix.  Notably, programs like Perl aren't always available on Windows.  But pure Bash; ouch!

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
find . -name "*HEX20*" -exec rename HEX20 HEX8 '{}' +
```

This will search recursively through the current directory and any subdirectories to match `HEX20`. (The flag `-type f` is omitted because the asker wants to change the names of directories in addition to files.) It will then build a long `rename` command and ultimately call it. This type of construction may be simpler than building a series of commands with `sed` and then executing them one-by-one.

Comment: kewl, didnt know about the -exec was thinking pipe to eval or xargs

Comment: @amdixon `-exec` is super helpful and powerful, but can be pretty dangerous. I like [this guide](http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/Find/using_exec_option_and_xargs_in_find.shtml) which details how to use it but also everything that can go wonderfully, horrible wrong.

Comment: i guess thats where the user has to know the files are safe ( under user control ) ie not named maliciously like "rm -rf /*" and testing to confirm the output generation before the -exec

Comment: Thanks for the neat solution, but I get an ERROR: Bareword "HEX20" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (eval1) line 1.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find . -type f -name "*HEX20*" |  sed 's/\(.*\)HEX20\(.*\)/mv \0 \1HEX8\2/' | sh
```

This way you find for regular files having `HEX20` in their names:

```
find . -type f -name "*HEX20*"
```

then change the last occurrence of `HEX20` whith `HEX8` and compile the `mv` command:

```
find . -type f -name "*HEX20*" |  sed 's/\(.*\)HEX20\(.*\)/mv \0 \1HEX8\2/'
```

finally you execute the compiled commands with `sh`:

```
find . -type f -name "*HEX20*" |  sed 's/\(.*\)HEX20\(.*\)/mv \0 \1HEX8\2/' | sh
```